# More than one events are added to an inner view backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

So here I have two views addBook and showBooks , the idea is, as I click on a button it should add a book name and author to the DOM its an

, and I should be able to click it. But the problem is for each

element more than one event handlers are added. that is for each new inner view more than one click events are added, I am quite new in backbone and I am still in Dark
here is my code , first the outer view

```
var addBook = Backbone.View.extend({
        el : $('#addbook'),
        model : bookmodel,
        template : _.template(addbookTemplate,{}),
        initialize : function(val){
            this.el.html(this.template);
            bookcollection.bind('add', this.showOff)
        },
        render : function(){
        },
        events : {
            'click #addbookbutton' : 'addHandler'
        },
        addHandler : function(){                
            var book =  new this.model;
book.addValues($('#bookname').val(), $('#bookauthor').val());
 bookcollection.add(book);


        },
        showOff : function(buk){
            this.xx = new showval({model: buk});
            $('#fatman').append((this.xx.render().el));
        }
    });
    return addBook;
```

Now the second and inner view

```
var showbooks = Backbone.View.extend({
        events : {
            'click .individual' : 'deleteHandler'
        },
        initialize : function(values){
            _.bindAll(this);
            /*if(values){*/

                //return this.template;
            //}
            //values = (values == "") ? {} : values;
            this.el.append(this.template);
        },
        render : function(){
            this.el = _.template(show, {name : "Max", author : "jk"});
            this.delegateEvents();
            return this;    
        },

        deleteHandler : function(e){
            alert("this kills me")
        }
    });
    return showbooks;
```

Now here is the problem as I click the button

is added to DOM button but for each new li one more alert is fired ... Help is highly appreciated , I know I am missing some crucial point .. !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken your code and changed it slightly. I have created 2 `Backbone.View`'s, one as the container and one for book items. It's crude, but hopefully will give you an idea of where you have gone wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/cQEu2/